# Operator <= cannot be applied to operands of type TKey

Tags: c#

`arg <= default(TKey)` produces

> Operator `<=` cannot be applied to operands of type `TKey`.

```
public class ParameterIdValidator<TKey> : IEndpointFilter
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{

    public async ValueTask<object?> InvokeAsync(EndpointFilterInvocationContext context, EndpointFilterDelegate next)
    {
        Type type = typeof(TKey);

        var arg = context.GetArgument<TKey>(0);    

        if
        (
            type == typeof(short) ||
            type == typeof(ushort) ||
            type == typeof(int) ||
            type == typeof(uint) ||
            type == typeof(long) ||
            type == typeof(ulong)
        )
        {    
            if (arg <= default(TKey))
            {
                return Results.BadRequest("Id must be positive!");
            }   
        }

        return await next(context);
    }
}
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to use `IComparable<>`, in my view:

```cs
if (arg is IComparable<TKey> key && 
    default(TKey) != null && // Protect against string, for example
    key.CompareTo(default(TKey)) <= 0)
{
    return Results.BadRequest("Id must be positive!");
}
```

You could remove the middle condition if you restricted `TKey` to be a value type, with `where TKey : struct`.

(In C# 11 there will be some more options here, but this seems like the simplest approach before then.)

Comment: I'd argue for `default(TKey) is TKey zero && key.CompareTo(zero) <= 0` as slightly more elegant.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I could go either way, to be honest. I think that explicitly mentioning null makes it clearer what we're protecting against, but I certainly don't strongly prefer that over your suggestion.

Comment: FWIW, the compiler doesn't care either -- it produces slightly different IL but the same object code (not that that's a primary concern, but it's always reassuring to know that one approach isn't much less efficient than the other).